# How do I delete a duplicate group using the group id?

Tags: user-management

I am using ubuntu 14.04 with MATE desktop. 
By mistake I created a group called `dba` two times with different ids: 1001 and 502
I want delete the group dba with id 1001.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

There may be a more elegant answer, but you can always edit `/etc/group` manually. You'll need root privileges, then just remove the line that includes the 1001 gid. It'll look something like this:

```
dba:x:1001:
```

Comment: I assume you then also need to move all users to the other group?

Comment: Hi Sparhawk,Thank you for your answer. It worked.

Comment: @Rinzwind I'm not sure if the OP actually did anything with this group or not.